# Finding Rank And Eignvalues Of Vectors Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v=(3,1,3,-4)$ and $A=v^tv$, Find:

1. the rank of $A$
2. $Null(A)$
3. eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Is there a way to approach this without finding $A$ explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=v^{t}*v$ will be a matrix of rank 1 because without knowing the value of $v$, 3 of the rows will be a coefficient of one row. so $rank A =1$ and $null A=3$
because $null(A)=0$ we can say that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$
we now that
$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4=trace(A)=3^2+1^2+3^2+(-4)^2=35\Rightarrow \lambda_4=35$$

---

Edit: why do I tell $null(A)=3\Rightarrow \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$?

for every eigenvalue we define two concepts:
1-geometric multiplicity:the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$
2-algebraic multiplicity:the number of repeats of the root $\lambda$ in the characteristic equation of matrix
we always have $geometric\;\; multiplicity\le algebraic\;\; multiplicity$
by definition for eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have $(A-\lambda I)X=\vec 0$ so
eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$=null space ($A-\lambda I$)
eigenspace corresponding to $(\lambda=0)$=null space ($A$)
we know that $null(A)=3$ so null space of A is 3-dimensional and eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=0$ is 3-dimensional then:
geometric multiplicity of $(\lambda=0)=3$ hence
 geometric algebraic of $(\lambda=0)=3 meaning that 3 of the eigenvalues should be zero

Comment: How can we know "3 of the rows will be a coefficient of one row"?

Is it because $A$ is linear combination of $3v+v+3v-4v$?

Comment: yes. just consider an arbitrary vector $(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1)$ if you do the multiplication, you will simply deduce that for an n-dimentional vector $v$,$v^t*v$ is always a matrix of rank 1 and nullity=n-1

Comment: How can I find the basis of $\lambda=0$ it is the equation (3,1,3,-4)?

Comment: Can you explain this more "because null(A)=0 we can say that λ1=λ2=λ3=0" mean?

Comment: @gbox yes just wait for several minutes

Comment: @gbox I will edit my answer to illustrate it

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is a rank-one operator: for any $w$, you have
$$
Aw^t=(v^tv)w^t=v^t(vw^t)=(vw^t)v^t
$$
(since $vw^t$ is a number). So the range of $A$ consists of the scalar multiplies of $v^t$.

The nullity is the the orthogonal complement of $v^t$.

The vector $v^t$ is an eigenvector, since
$$
Av^t=v^tvv^t=(9+1+9+16)v^t=35v^t.
$$
So the eigenvalue corresponding to $v^t$ is 35. The only other eigenvalue is $0$ with multiplicity (both algebraic and geometric) equal  to $3$.

Comment: I am trying to find a basis for the eigenvalue $0$ I came down to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 
-3 & -1 & -3 &4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$
How can I find a basis with just 1 equation?

Answer (score 2):

Here $v\in M_{1\times 4}$ is rank one. The rank-nullity theorem implies that 
$$
\dim\DeclareMathOperator{null}{null}\null v
=\dim\Bbb R^4-\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank v
= 4-1
= 3
$$
Let $\{\vec n_1,\vec n_2,\vec n_3\}$ be a basis for $\null v$.

The equation 
$$
Av^\top=\left(v^\top v\right)v^\top=v^\top\left(v v^\top\right)=\lVert v\rVert v^\top
$$
implies that $\lambda_1=\lVert v\rVert$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v^\top$.

The equation
$$
A \vec n_k=\left(v^\top v\right)\vec n_k=v^\top\left(v\vec n_k\right)=v^\top\vec 0=\vec 0
$$
implies that $\lambda_2=0$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ and that $\{\vec n_1,\vec n_2,\vec n_3\}$ are eigenvectors associated to $\lambda_2=0$.

This proves that $A$ is diagonalizable and similar to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lVert v\rVert &0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence (a) the rank of $A$ is one, (b) $\null(A)=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{\vec n_1,\vec n_2,\vec n_3\}$, and (c) the eigenpairs of $A$ are
\begin{align*}
\left(\lVert v\rVert,v^\top\right)
&&
(0,\vec n_1)
&&
(0,\vec n_2)
&&
(0,\vec n_3)
\end{align*}

Now, if you'd like to compute a basis for $\null v$, note that
$
v\vec x=\vec 0
$
if and only if
$$
3\,x_1+x_2+3\,x_3-4\,x_4=0
$$
That is, $v\vec x=\vec 0$ if and only if 
\begin{align*}
\vec x
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1& -3\,x_1-3\,x_3+4\,x_4&x_3&x_4
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=x_1\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&0&0\end{bmatrix}+x_3\begin{bmatrix}0&-3&1&0\end{bmatrix}+x_4\begin{bmatrix}0&4&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
This implies that
\begin{align*}
\vec n_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}1&-3&0&0\end{bmatrix}&
\vec n_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}0&-3&1&0\end{bmatrix}&
\vec n_3 &= \begin{bmatrix}0&4&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
are (non-unique!) suitable choices for $\vec n_1$, $\vec n_2$, and $\vec n_3$.